# Call function based on component Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have three components (profile, page, group) and each of these component called `<app-posts [data]="post"></app-posts>` and in my `posts.component.html` I have this `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="load-more-button" (click)="myQuestion()">Load More</a>
```

I want to replace `myQuestion()` function based on which component I'm in now, if I'm in profile I want `myQuestion()` to be `myProfile()`, same thing with page and group.

I think about make service for each component and check every time where I'm I but it is silly way in my opinion, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**posts.component.ts**

In your `posts.component.ts` define an `@Output()` binding called `loadMore`. Everytime a user clicks the link an `event` will emit and delegate this event to his parent component (page, group, profile)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  template: `
   <a id="load-more-button" (click)="loadMore.emit()">Load More</a>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent {

  @Input() data: any;

  @Output() loadMore: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**profile, page, group component.ts**

In your parent component listen to `loadMore` events.

For example profile:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  template: `
   <app-posts [data]="profiles" (loadMore)="onLoadMoreProfiles()"></app-posts>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent {

  profiles: any

  onLoadMoreProfiles() {
   // load more profile or whatever
  }      


}
```

Repead this pattern for `group.component.ts` and `page.component.ts`

For more information check the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Great! but what if I want to call this function in my `post.component.ts` what is the default `loadmore` value would be?

Comment: I am not clear what do you exactly mean, but with my approach you can decouple functionallity from `posts component.ts`. As you already import data to your `posts.component.ts` you fetch them somewhere and it is good practice to add the "fetch more" functionallity at the same place where you fetch them initialy. That makes your code more reasonable and understandable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is just to pass an attribute value which will let your component know what should be its behavior in the current context. And depending on that handle that inside you `myQuesition()` function.

So in 3 places, you pass to your components different values:

```
<app-posts [data]="post" [profile]="'question'"></app-posts>
<app-posts [data]="post" [profile]="'profile'"></app-posts>
<app-posts [data]="post" [profile]="'question'"></app-posts>
```

Your view:

```
 <a id="load-more-button" (click)="question()">Load More</a>
```

And in your `posts.component.ts`:

```
export class FriendComponent {
    @Input() funcType: string = 'profile';

    constructor() {}

    question(){
        if(this.funcType === 'profile'){
           this.myQuestion();
         } else if (this.funcType === 'question'){
           this.myProfile();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the function address in the component itself

**component.ts**

```
export default class MyComponent {
    //myFunctionAdress = /** assign function based on component**/;
    //example:
    myFunctionAdress = this.myFuncion;

    myFunction() {

    }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<a (click)="myFunctionAdress()">Load More</a>
```